# Ferromagnetic sphere placed in uniform field

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

Imagine a ferromagnetic sphere, which I assume that it originally contains no magnetisation, is placed inside a uniform magnetic field as shown in the following image:

[image]

In the image, B is externally applied magnetic field and φ is defined such that H = −∇φ.

I would like to solve for the value of φ both inside and outside the sphere.  Using Maxwell's second equation and assuming that the divergence of magnetisation is zero, I can write down the Laplace equation Δφ = 0.

I'm thinking about solving the Laplace equation by separating it into functions in spherical coordinates.  Is it valid to guess that the solution is in the form:

[image]

I've guessed that the potential created by the sphere is only dependent on cosθ, but not higher order terms of the Legendre expansion.  I've put it into a computer simulation and it, indeed, worked.  However, how do I know that higher order terms of the Legendre expansion vanishes?

Comment: the combined field must approach asymptotically the external field as $r \to \infty $.

Comment: @hyportnex I am aware of that but I'm not sure about the other terms. Why did I include C/r^2*cos(θ) but not, say, a term like E/r^3(cos^2(θ)+1)?

Comment: Because of the $C/r^2$ term you have asymptotically a dipole field superimposed over a constant field external bias, and in general, unless the dipole term is zero *everything* from a finite size source is asymptotically a dipole field. Using the continuity of the tangential "H" and normal "B" components you can now find all the unknown coefficients; the resulting $\phi$ will satisfy the Poisson equation, and you are done.

Comment: @hyportnex (1) How do we know the dipole term (in $\phi_{out}$) *isn't* zero, in which case we need higher-order terms to approximate the potential far away? (2) Why do we need to approximate the dipole term anyway, given that the dominant $r^1$ term is there? (3) Why are we justified in leaving off higher-order terms for $\phi_{in}$?

Comment: @WillG (1) we do not *know* but we can *guess* because we are talking about a soft magnetic material whose magnetism is induced by an external field.  (2) we need the dipole field because the $r^1$ term is from the bias field and by itself does not satisfy the boundary conditions (continuity) (3) we are justified leaving off the higher order terms because with these two terms we do satisfy the continuity condition *and* the Poisson equation. Check it out!

Comment: @hyportnex Fair. I just had this Q on a final exam and I wish I had been able to reason through it! (It seems a bit post-hoc, like you need to expect this answer going into the problem.) Is there a general set of conditions that guarantee an object will have *only* a dipole moment (and no other moments) induced when placed in a uniform B-field?

Comment: @WillG It is possible to find the solution more systematically using symmetry arguments and separation of variables resulting in an expansion in spherical harmonics. Then matching the fields at the magnetizable sphere's boundary and at infinity you get the desired result. What both this and the more ad hoc scheme I described lack is the intuition why the *internal* field must be uniform (this is true for any prolate ellipsoid not just a sphere); unfortunately, I cannot help you there...

Answer (score 2):

One can demonstrate this by applying boundary conditions to the general solution of Laplace's equation with azimuthal symmetry:

$$ V(r,\theta ) = \sum ^{\infty} _{l=0} \left( A_l r^l + \frac{B_l}{r^{l+1}} \right) P_l (\cos \theta )) $$

We now insist that the potential remains finite everywhere and tends to $ -\frac{B_{0}}{\mu{0}}z = - \frac{B_{0}}{\mu_{0}}rcos(\theta) $ so that $\mathbf{H} = -\nabla{V} = \frac{B_{0}}{\mu_{0}}\hat{z} $, giving:

$$ V_{in} = \sum ^{\infty} _{l=0}  A_l r^l P_l (\cos \theta ) $$

$$ V_{out} = \sum ^{\infty} _{l=0} \frac{B_l}{r^{l+1}} P_l (\cos \theta ) - \frac{B_{0}}{\mu_{0}}rcos(\theta) $$

We now apply the following boundary conditions at the surface r = a:

1. Continuity of the potential:  $ V(a,\theta )_{in} = V(a,\theta )_{out} $
2. $ \mathbf{H_{in}^{\perp}} + \mathbf{M_{in}^{\perp}} = \mathbf{H_{out}^{\perp}}$ which follows from $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$

The first boundary condition gives us:

$$B_{l}a^{-(l+1)}  = A_{l} $$  for $  l\neq 1$, and

$$B_{1}a^{-3}  = A_{1} - \frac{B_{0}}{\mu_{0}} $$ for $  l= 1$

Before applying the second boundary condition, we must make the assumption that $\mathbf{M}$ is a constant vector pointing in the z-direction:

$$ \mathbf{M} = M\mathbf{\hat{z}} = M(cos\theta 
\mathbf{\hat{r}}  -sin\theta \hat{\mathbf{\theta}}) $$

The perpendicular components which feature in the second boundary condition are the $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ - components of the vectors, so:

$$ -\frac{\partial{V_{in}}}{\partial{r}} + Mcos{\theta} = -\frac{\partial{V_{out}}}{\partial{r}} $$

We can now plug in our values for $ V_{in} $ ,$V_{out}$, and $ M $:

$$ -l A_{l}a^{l-1} = -(l+1)B_{l}a^{-(l+2)}   $$ for $  l\neq 1$, and

$$- A_{1} +M = - \frac{B_{0}}{\mu_{0}} -2B_{1}a^{-3}  $$ for $  l= 1$

Looking at the equations concerning  $l\neq 1$, it follows that $A_{l} = B_{l} = 0$ for $l\neq 1$. However, the equations concerning $l=1$ terms in the potential can be simultaneously solved to find nonzero $A_{1},  B_{2} $ in terms of $B_{0}$ and $M$. Finally, to make contact with the question, call $B_{1} = C $ and $A_{1} = D$

Comment: How to get the value of M in this one? Will susceptibility of the material help?